# Logout through spring-security code

Tags: java, spring, junit, spring-security

In my junit i would like to be able to logout a user.

here is my junit login function:

```
protected void loginPlayer(String loginName) {

System.out.println("Logging in player: " + loginName);
Player player = this.playerRepository.findPlayerByLoginName(loginName);
UserDetails playerSession = new PlayerSession(player.getId(), loginName, player.getPassword());
Authentication auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(playerSession, null, playerSession.getAuthorities());
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
}
```

how do i achieve a logout using a similar methodology?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [SecurityContextHolder API](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/context/SecurityContextHolder.html) you should be able to call SecurityContextHolder.clearContext()

Comment: that clears all sessions? I want to clear only a specific user session

Comment: This clears the security context for the current thread. Since spring security authentication is thread bound this will invalidate the user authentication you have shown in your example.

Answer (score 0):

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(null);
```

Comment: that clears all sessions? I want to clear only a specific user session